# VSCode extensions cannot access network

Tags: visual-studio-code

The extensions work most of the time. But when I start remote development, all extensions cannot access network.

Error messages like

```
Couldn't download IntelliCode model. Please check your network connectivity or firewall settings.
```

Comment: Can you clarify "remote development"? Is the machine running VSCode behind some kind of firewall or proxy? Have you tried downloading the VSIX file from the web-based marketplace and installing using that?

Comment: use Remote - Containers exetnsiom to use a local Docker container as environment. And the extensions are installed in the dev container

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem using the Ssh remote extension and here is how I solved it.

My local machine is a Windows machine. I have a local cntlm proxy running. Remote SSH works flawlessly, downloading extensions using this proxy.

My remote machine is a linux machine. In my .bashrc I set my *http*_proxy variables to another proxy. In my terminal, these variables are correctly set, but I don't think that VSCode sees them.

**Solution:**: In the *Remote settings*  I configured:

- Http: Proxy Support as *override*
- Http: Proxy as my *remote **http** proxy*. When I set an http**s** proxy url here, it failed.
- proxyStrictSSL is set as `false`

Now I can see in the logs that the model is correctly downloaded.

There is a [bug open](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/intellicode/issues/218) in VSCode repository.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, basically the proxy was the culprit. All the time a remote was started that message "Couldn't download IntelliCode model. Please check your network connectivity or firewall settings." was printed.

The solution to me was the proxy variables in the ".bashrc" (or the equivalent for other SHELL) on the remote Host; then after a new remote connection VSCode will call "set_proxy" to download the extensions.

After that use "set_proxy" or "unset_proxy" to modify the variables.

```sh
set_proxy ()
{
  echo "export http(s)_proxy"
  export  http_proxy=http://<YOURPROXY>:<PORT>  ; \
  export https_proxy="${http_proxy}" ; \
  export   ftp_proxy="${http_proxy}" ; \
  export   FTP_PROXY="${http_proxy}" ; \
  export  HTTP_PROXY="${http_proxy}" ; \
  export HTTPS_PROXY="${http_proxy}" ; \
  export no_proxy=<NOPROXY_VALUES>; \
  export NO_PROXY="${no_proxy}" ;
}

unset_proxy ()
{
  echo "unset http(s)_proxy"
  unset http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy FTP_PROXY HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY no_proxy NO_PROXY
}

set_proxy
```